# A quadratic inequality related to the $\log$ function

Tags: inequality, machine-learning, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite

Suppose that $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that their sum is $0$.Show that for all positive real number $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ the following inequality holds:
$$ \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n} c_ic_j \log(x_i+x_j) \leq 0$$

*Where this problem comes from*: the original problem is related to the concept of kernel in the field of machine learning. The problem asks me to show that the kernel $K(x,y) := \log(x+y), x,y>0$ is a NDS(negative definite symmetric) kernel, which is equivalent to the problem stated at the beginning.

A result in machine learning states that $K$ is a NDS kernel iff $\exp(-tK)$ is a PDS kernel for all $t>0$, thus the problem can be reduced to showing that
$$[(x_i+x_j)^{-t}]_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$$ 
is a positive semi-definite matrix. Furthermore, we only need to prove this result for $0<t<1$ because the matrix $$[(x_i+x_j)^{-1}]_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$$ is positive semi-definite(as a special case of the Cauchy matrix), and if $(a_{ij})$and $(b_{ij})$ are positive semi-definite then $(a_{ij}b_{ij})$ is also positive semi-definite.

**QUESTION**

How to prove the above inequality, either directly or by showing instead that the generalized Cauchy matrix is positive semi-definite?

Comment: Are $c_i$'s distinct? or is it possible that $c_i = c_j$ for some $i,j$?

Comment: Sorry,there is a typo in the problem;Iwould edit it.the $c_i$sneed not be different.

Comment: @j200932 I (also) upvoted; very interesting question.  Obviously, the conjecture is true for $n=2.$  I would consider the conjecture when $n=3$ and when $n=4.$  First verify that the conjecture must be true in those cases.  Then look for some pattern in **why** the conjecture is true for $n=3$ and $n=4.$  Then consider **either** proof by induction on $n$ **or** proof in the general case based on some pattern found when $n=3$ or $n=4.$

Comment: @j2000932 Re my previous comment: I was giving an **uneducated** generic attack.  I have never before seen the term *Cauchy matrix* or the term *positive-semidefinite.*  There may well be a (much) better approach that requires that the person is better educated and thus able to **avoid** having to re-invent the wheel, as my approach may be attempting.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your reply and I find that I have misused the term ‘Cauchy matrix’. Cauchy matrices aren’t always positive semidefinite but in this special case it is.By ‘positive semidefinite’ I refer to a symmetric matrix $(a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j \geq 0$ holds for all real numbers $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick way of seeing this might be to note that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-at}}{t}\,dt = \log a \,, \forall a > 0.$$

So the quadratic form above can be written as \begin{align*} \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n} c_ic_j \log(x_i + x_j) &= \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n} c_ic_j \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t} - e^{-(x_i+x_j)t}}{t}\,dt \\&= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}\left(e^{-t}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\right)^2 - \left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_je^{-x_jt}\right)^2\right)\,dt \\&= -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_je^{-x_jt}\right)^2 \,dt \le 0\end{align*} where, we used the fact that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n c_j = 0$.